# c++ ifstream getline() loop only returns last line of the txt file

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I am trying to write a function that takes in filename and line number and return a string from that specific line. The problem is my function only returns a string when it is reading the last line of the file while reading other lines returns nothing.

Here's my function: (My line parameter starts from 0 so 8 is actually 9th line)

```
string txtRW_readline(string FileName,int Line){
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(FileName.c_str());

    string txtline;

    for(int i = 0; i <= Line ; i++){
        getline(fin,txtline);
        cout << "Reading line: " << i << endl;
        cout << "Result: " << txtline << endl << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "Returning: " << txtline << endl;
    return txtline;
}

int main(){
    cout << txtRW_readline("input.txt",8);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my input.txt:

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
E5
F6
G7
H8
I9
```

Here's my output: (when cout << txtRW_readline("input.txt",8))

```
Reading line: 0
Result: A1

Reading line: 1
Result: B2

Reading line: 2
Result: C3

Reading line: 3
Result: D4

Reading line: 4
Result: E5

Reading line: 5
Result: F6

Reading line: 6
Result: G8

Reading line: 7
Result: H8

Reading line: 8
Result: I9

Returning: I9
I9  <-- This one returns a line
```

Here's my output: (when cout << txtRW_readline("input.txt",7))

```
Reading line: 0
Result: A1

Reading line: 1
Result: B2

Reading line: 2
Result: C3

Reading line: 3
Result: D4

Reading line: 4
Result: E5

Reading line: 5
Result: F6

Reading line: 6
Result: G8

Reading line: 7
Result: H8


Returning: H8
<-- This one returns nothing -->
```

Can anyone please explains to me why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's what he wants... he wants to return only a certain line

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/mvS2Lb). When calling `readline` with `7`, I **do** get `H8` output at the end (scroll down for output on that ideone link).

Comment: @donpsabance got it. พอดี พู่เจริญ, the line you print is probablly just overwritten by your prompt (or it's at the beginning of the prompt). Add a newline: `cout << txtRW_readline("input.txt",7) << "\n";`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this... I can only suggest you to use while loop and check if the line is actually being read and incrementing line count inside the loop, otherwise you could read nothing past the file and that might be one of many problems that aren't rare for IO if you don't check.

Comment: I also can't reproduce. I get the proper output...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just added a new line and it works!! Thank you so much I did not notice that.